# Is it possible to have multiple separate ternary expressions in ng-class for an element?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to combine the following two `ng-class` ternary expressions into one `ng-class` (so I can control both the color, via btn-success/danger classes, and the width, via width-small/medium/wide class, of my button divs

```
<div class="btn" ng-class="(rate > 0) ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'">{{rate}}</div>
<div class="btn" ng-class="(priority == 'low') ? 'width-small' : (priority == 'medium') ? 'width-medium' : 'width-wide'">{{rate}}</div>
```

I realize I could just do something along the lines of below; however, I would like to make use of the ternary expressions available in 1.1.5

```
<div class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-success': rate > 0, 'btn-danger': rate <= 0, 'width-small': priority == 'low', 'width-medium': priority == 'medium', 'width-wide': prioity == 'high'}">{{rate}}</div>
```

Space separating the expressions did not work for me, nor did comma separating them within `ng-class`

Thanks advance for your assistance in determining if/how to have multiple ternary expressions in a single `ng-class`

Comment: Why would you want to use the ternary operator there? The way you've written it using the "object" version of ng-class is much cleaner in my opinion. I find your line with the widths with the two ternary operators very difficult to read, but the object version with everything separated out is highly readable.

Comment: @ksimons is right on here, chaining ternaries is never easier to read. I'd +1 him forty more times if I could.

Comment: @ksimons you're right, the ternary operators are a mess to read and I'm just going to stick with the more readable option (it works, so why make things more complicated?)

Comment: I'm also interested if this is possible.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer: Yes this is indeed possible, also as mentioned the readability is questionable.

```
<div ng-class="(conversation.read ? 'read' : 'unread') + ' ' + (conversation.incoming ? 'in' : 'out')"></div>
```

From the ngClass documentation:

> The directive operates in three different ways, depending on which of >three types the expression evaluates to:
>
> 1. If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or >more space-delimited class names.
> 2. If the expression evaluates to an array, each element of the array >should >be a string that is one or more space-delimited class names.
> 3. If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of >the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class >name.

Option 1 applies here.

From my understanding using this method will result in 2 watches while using object notation will result in 4, but I might be wrong on this one.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to add multiple ternary expressions on a single ng-class directive by putting each of the expressions into an array, as items of this array.

Example :

```
<div ng-class="[
    expression1 ? 'class1' : 'class2',
    expression2 ? 'class3' : 'class4'
]">
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you'd rather use a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters). You could write a `rateToClass` filter that would hold the logic and transform your rate in the class name that you want.

You could also put a rateToClass(rate) function in your scope, but it's ugly.

If you insist on having your logic in the view, 
`ng-class` support multiple classes by using an object (see [official doc first example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass), line 7):

`<p ng-class="{strike: strike, bold: bold, red: red}">Map Syntax Example</p>`

You can have more complexe expression like `ng-class='{btn-success: rate > 0}`'.

Comment: While I am still curious if there is a way to have multiple classes determined by ternary expressions in a single `ngclass`, I agree with @ksimons that the object approach, as you and I also mentioned, is a clearer approach (that works just fine)

Comment: So, you a curious if there is a dirtier way to make something that can be achieved in a simpler and clean maintainable way. I think you are wasting you time.

Comment: Fair enough, but I do see some appeal to using ternary operators for the sake of not having to write expressions and then write their opposites (especially if the expression and its inverse are more complex than a simple greater-than, as I used...but, yes, objects work just fine so I'll stick with them