# Using ternary operator notation for ng-class for multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to display data, one of which is the value for a progress bar, and depending on conditions, I need to change the progress bars colour.

I have it working for one of the conditions using syntax, `patent.costBandColour == 'Blue' ? 'bg-phase-black': ''`, like so:

```
<uib-progress ng-class="patent.costBandColour == 'Blue' ? 'bg-phase-black': ''">
    <uib-bar value="patent.progressBar">{{patent.progressBar}}%</uib-
</uib-progress>
```

I need to add 5 conditions to this single ng-class. I attempted to add a second condition so the syntax looks like so:

`patent.costBandColour == 'Blue' ? 'bg-phase-black': '' patent.costBandColour == 'Red' ? 'bg-phase-blue': ''`

But an error shows:

> Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 55 of the
>   expression [patent.costBandColour == 'Blue' ? 'bg-phase-black': '',
>   patent.costBandColour == 'Red' ? 'bg-phase-blue': ''] starting at [,
>   patent.costBandColour == 'Red' ? 'bg-phase-blue': ].

***Question***

Where in my syntax am I going wrong? It says that the `,` is the error, so how do I bind multiple conditionals?

Comment: Apologies, just found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573634/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-separate-ternary-expressions-in-ng-class-for-an. Have to concat multiple expressions with `(expression)+ ' ' +(expression)`

Comment: try this: patent.costBandColour == 'Blue' ? 'bg-phase-black': patent.costBandColour == 'Red' ? 'bg-phase-blue': '' : ''

Comment: You can also do `ng-class="{'bg-phase-black': patent.costBandColour == 'Blue', 'bg-phase-blue': patent.costBandColour == 'Red'}"`

Comment: @palash I tried that method but it didn't work :/